# Cannot read property 'img' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2 -> I'm getting an error on this page with the Superbox.js script located here. http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/wp-content/themes/bvh/js/portfolio/superbox.js

Console states on line 51 that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of null

Right now on line 51 it states the following.

```
var imgData = currentimg.data();
superboximg.attr('src', imgData.img);
```

I don't see anything wrong with this but I am confused as to why I'm getting this error.

Any thoughts or help is appreciated!

Comment: I believe it is being defined here.
var currentimg = $(this).find('.superbox-img');

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Provide a *complete*, reduced test case instead.

Comment: var superboximg   = $('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img span7">'); This is I got from your script file. See the src="" so its not getting img source and hence it cant read property of null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `data-img` attribute that contains the path of the image. [Here](https://github.com/toddmotto/superbox/blob/master/index.html) is an example.

```
    <img src="img/superbox/superbox-thumb-24.jpg" data-img="img/superbox/superbox-full-24.jpg" alt="" class="superbox-img">
```

Comment: Yea you are right. I will need to find a way to display it without that data-img attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to state if its in the description show the image without a data-img attribute? 

if (imgData.description) { superboxcontent.append('<div class="description">' + imgData.description + '</div>'); }

Comment: @bryanlewis What exatcly are you trying to do? Should it show the image specified in src instead? I recommend you create a new question about that. ;)

Comment: yea, I'm trying to get it to show the image specified in src instead. Will make a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Can only post every 20 minutes. Guess I'll have to wait.